# Как обновить версию Nest CLI на Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, nestjs

Я занимаюсь разработкой на NestJS. Когда ввожу команду `nest i`, то получаю такую информацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что версия 8.2.8 меня не устраивает и мне нужна срочно более новая версия? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обновить именно nest cli (или как его удалить, чтобы я его мог занова скачать)

Comment: ``nest update`` не работает?

Comment: нужно обновить именно nest cli, а не приложение на nestjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас уже установлена определенная версия Nest CLI и вы хотите обновить ее до более новой версии, вы можете использовать команду npm update с указанием пакета и желаемой версии для обновления. Вот как это сделать:

Откройте терминал.

Выполните команду обновления, указав имя пакета Nest CLI и желаемую версию. Замените <desired_version> на версию, до которой вы хотите обновить Nest CLI, и укажите пакет @nestjs/cli:

```bash
npm update -g @nestjs/cli@<desired_version>
```

Например, если у вас установлена версия 7.0.0, и вы хотите обновиться до версии 8.0.0, выполните следующую команду:

```bash
npm update -g @nestjs/cli@8.0.0
```

После завершения обновления, вы можете проверить установленную версию, выполнив команду:

```bash
nest --version
```

Теперь у вас установлена конкретная версия Nest CLI, которую вы указали в команде обновления. Убедитесь, что указываете версию без ошибок при выполнении команды обновления.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Для обновления версии Nest CLI на Ubuntu 22.04 вы можете использовать следующие команды:

Откройте терминал.

Установите Nest CLI с помощью npm (если ещё не установлен):

```bash
npm install -g @nestjs/cli
```

Для обновления Nest CLI до последней версии, выполните следующую команду:

```bash
npm update -g @nestjs/cli
```

После завершения обновления, вы можете убедиться в том, что Nest CLI обновился, выполнив следующую команду:

```bash
nest --version
```

Это позволит вам убедиться, что вы используете последнюю версию Nest CLI на вашем Ubuntu 22.04. Убедитесь, что у вас установлен Node.js и npm на вашей системе, прежде чем выполнить эти команды.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)